# Ansible aws_ec2 inventory never matching host group

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-pull

So firstly, I probably missing something really simple here and I just can't see it.  I am trying to use ansible pull with aws_ec2 inventory pluggin to run on a EC2 instance in AWS using packer.  I have the following inventory file:

```
plugin: aws_ec2
regions:
  - eu-west-1
  - eu-west-2
keyed_groups:
  - key: tags['role']
    prefix: enc
filters:
  instance-state-name: running
  tag:ami: "true
```

and when I run `ansible-inventory -i /tmp/ansible/inventories/dev/ami_inventory_aws_ec2.yml --list` I get the following groups:

```
"all": {
        "children": [
            "aws_ec2",
            "enc_web",
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    },
    "aws_ec2": {
        "hosts": [
            "ip-10-93-66-209.eu-west-1.compute.internal"
        ]
    },
    "enc_web": {
        "hosts": [
            "ip-10-93-66-209.eu-west-1.compute.internal"
        ]
    }
```

which is what I expect to see. Then in my playbook I have the following:

```
---
- import_playbook: bootstrap.yml

- hosts: enc_web
  gather_facts: True
  roles:
    - name: enc.base
....
```

At this point I would of thought that running `ansible-pull` or `ansible-playblook` with or without `--limit enc_web` ansible would of matched the group name and run, but instead I am getting

```
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: ami-aws-web-01
ERROR! Specified hosts and/or --limit does not match any hosts
```

I am I missing something really basic here?  Should it run against all hosts in that group name?

My full ansible command is:

```
ansible-pull --url=git@bitbucket.org:XXXXX/ansible.git --accept-host-key --directory=/tmp/ansible --full --checkout=web --private-key=/home/ubuntu/.ssh/ansible/ansible -e ami=true -e region=eu-west-1 --vault-password-file=~/.ssh/ansible/dev --inventory-file=/tmp/ansible/inventories/dev/ami_inventory_aws_ec2.yml playbooks/web.yml --limit enc_web
```

Comment: I don't see a hot named "ami-aws-web-01" in the output of `ansible-inventory`. In any case, I think when using `ansible-pull` it's more common to simply target `localhost`, since you're running the playbooks on the host they are meant to configure.

Comment: ok so you cant put whole heap of hosts into a group and say deploy to that group and I don't care the name of the host?

Comment: You can do that, but the host needs to be a member of the group, which it isn't. That's the problem.

Comment: right makes sense, I changed the aws_ec2 plug to map the Name tag as the host name and now everything works. Thanks for the help @larsks

Answer (score 0):

Changed the inventory file to:

```
plugin: aws_ec2
regions:
 - eu-west-1
 - eu-west-2
keyed_groups:
 - key: tags['role']
    prefix: enc
filters:
  instance-state-name: running
  tag:ami: "true"
hostnames:
 - tag:Name
```

When then make the host name what was needed to match.